# Do players have to discard when a Knight card is played?

Tags: catan

In Settlers of Catan, when a player plays a Knight card ("Solider" card in older editions), do players with 8 cards or more in their hand have to forfeit half their hand to the bank?

This is causing a huge row in our family as I think that this forfeit rule only applies to rolling a seven and not to playing a Knight card.

Answer (score 16):

No, you don't lose half your hand if a knight card is played.

The rules for 'rolling a 7 and activating the Robber' state

> every player who was more than 7 Resource Cards must select half (rounded down) of his Resource Cards and return them to the bank.
>
> The you must move the robber Proceed as follows.....

then steps 1 and 2 are stated for stealing a resource.

The rules for a solider cards state

> you must immediately move the robber.  See activating the robber and and follow steps 1 and 2

It does not state everyone loses cards if they have 8 or more.

To clarify the rules for losing cards if you have more than 8 are only triggered for rolling a 7 and in no other way.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In fact I found the answer on the [catan.com website FAQ's](http://www.catan.com/faq-page/93) Know it all son has been informed. His response was that I could not possibly have known that at the time so I was obviously cheated. Looks like a good game (this is only my second game), but I might need to find somebody else to play it with!

Comment: Sounds like someone is a sore loser. :) Lots of kids struggle with it, especially motivated ones! Good life lessons.